# jenkins nightwatch email report

Tags: jenkins, nightwatch.js

Has anyone created a simple email report that Jenkins sends out when nightwatch builds fail? or event converted junit reports to email reports?

I would like the following information in a concise report:

- Failures
- List of code changes
- Who was the last people to commit

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a public version, but let me try to offer some assistance how you can combine nodemailer with nightwatch-html-reporter.

I have a working nightwatch located at https://github.com/shane-reaume/nightwatch-bones

You should be able to see where the nightwatch-html-reporter code lives in the globals.js as...

```
var reporter = new HtmlReporter({
  openBrowser: true,
  reportsDirectory: __dirname + '/reports/',
  themeName: 'default',
  reportFilename: os.split(' ').join('-') + '-report.html'
});
```

Here you are creating an html file. With that you can extract the html for your nodemailer (see https://community.nodemailer.com/).

It seems to be relatively easy if you follow the directions on each, but let me know if you have trouble and I can try to throw something together.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to go with the email-extension plugin.
follow the documentation https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin
you can mail the reports as attachements to respective emails sepperating by commas

Comment: While the link may contain a solution for OP'S problem, just providing a link doesnt solve a question. Imagine if the link expires one day, your answer will be useless then. So please explain the main aspects in your answer and add the link only as a reference for your written information.

Comment: I am sorry for that. as it is jenkins original doc i hope it will not expire. and there you can find a clear setup how to do that with screenshots. that is the reason i suggest the URL link